# Retrieving form data from Jade - Node.js

Tags: node.js, file, input, express, pug

So I am trying to retrieve a file upload and a number via a Jade file, but only one will register.

Jade file:

```
form#fileUpload(name="fileUpload", method="POST", action="/fileUpload", enctype="multipart/form-data")
        input#userInputFile(type="file", name="logName")
        button(type="submit") Upload

form#userNumErr(name="numError", method="POST", action="/fileUpload")
          input#userInputNum(type="number", name="numerr", placeholder="Number of Errors")
          button(type="submit") Submit
```

Index.js File:

```
/* POST the file upload */
router.post("/fileUpload", function (req, res) {

    var numErrors = req.body.numerr;

    // TODO: Getting form value
    console.log("User input is: " + numErrors);

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

        fs.readFile(files.logName.path, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
```

If I input the number and then try to upload the file, it renders an error that 'path' is undefined. However, when I upload the file, it won't let me the read the number input.
For context, I want the user input in order to manipulate how many lines get printed out of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to submit two separate forms. Put both fields into the same form so that they get POSTed together.

```
form#fileUpload(name="fileUpload", method="POST", action="/fileUpload", enctype="multipart/form-data")
    input#userInputFile(type="file", name="logName")
    input#userInputNum(type="number", name="numerr", placeholder="Number of Errors")
    button(type="submit") Upload
```

Comment: I've tried that first, but it does not work. I'm guessing because the enctype of the form is set to "multipart/form-data"

Comment: [It should absolutely work](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). Are you sure you're accessing your data correctly? Maybe try double checking what's on the `files.logName` object.

Comment: @user3303917 you're also using formidable here. Do you have any other middleware in your app setup? Express bodyparser? Maybe it messes with formidable. 
Btw, bodyParser will also parse files for you. What do yo get on the router if you `console.log(req.body.numErr)`? Do you also get the file if you log `console.log(req.body.files)`?